# I got this error "error: package com.google.firebase.messaging does not exist"

Tags: android, gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'

}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.code.zero.drivermechanicsapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }    
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'

        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

        }) 

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
        compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.0.5'
        //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
        //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
    }
}
```

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

Answer (score 3):

Have you included the correct dependencies in your `build.gradle` file? You can also use the Firebase Assistant.

Check out the [Documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for the Gradle requirements if you are including it manually.

In other words, add the following to your dependencies:

```gradle
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

Comment: and i got this error as i checked the build.gradle and i already updated the google-services on sdk tools

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: yes i did try the suggestions